# Python TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len() when running from console

Tags: python, pandas

Having the following piece of code that checks if a combination of IT01 + 8 exists for columns SG and PL and if so changes value from 8 to 6 in columns PL. If not it keep the original value.

```
cm_full_df['PL'] = np.where(cm_full_df.set_index(['SG', 'PL']).index.isin(zip(['IT01'],[8])), 6, cm_full_df['PL'])
```

I am able to smoothly run it in VS Code without any issue but when I run it via a CMD console I get the TypeError:

> TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()

So the dataset doesn't change but the way I run the script either raises the error or not. Can anyone advise?

Comment: `zip` in python2 returns a list. `zip` in python3 returns a iterator. Are you using the same python both places?

Comment: in both instances I'm using the same venv with Python 3.11.1

Comment: Well, zip objects do not have a length. Convert the iterator to a list `list(zip(['IT01'],[8])))` Not sure how it's working in VSCode

Comment: Your code never calls `len()`. Maybe you're using different versions of pandas?

Comment: For a minor digression on *why* they don't have a length, it's because iterators can be infinite: you can lazily consume an iterator of an infinite sequence. You can even zip two different infinite sequences and lazily consume the produced tuples. So it can't have a length because it might be infinite. Lists are finite though.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Maybe this is a Pandas bug that's gotten fixed. I'm using Pandas 2.0.3. To confirm, provide a [mre] including complete but minimal code and the [full error message with traceback](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). Also if it's relevant, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). What I tried was `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(5)}, index=zip(range(10, 15), range(20, 25)))` then `df.index.isin(zip([11], [21]))`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are getting inconsistent results... however, I can offer a fix to your error.

I would recommend wrapping the `zip()` with `list()` because `zip()` returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator), which is not what `isin()` is expecting. See the [`isin()` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) (*formatting is my own*).

> `Index.isin(values, level=None)`
>
> Parameters:
>
> - `values`: set or list-like
> - `level`: str or int, optional